# MS Access form not centering properly across different monitors

Tags: forms, ms-access, centering

I have an MS Access form where I have the main navigation page set to be centered and it works... kinda.

This form file has to be used on monitors of many different aspect ratios: 3:4, 16:9, and 21:9. When the form opens, it is properly centered in whatever window it opens. But when that window is then maximized, it doesn't re-center and instead sticks to the left side of the screen. Sometimes if I move it between monitors, the form is far 'off screen' in its own window and I have to scroll in the form to bring it into view, then it's stuck on the right hand side of the form.

Is there a way to force the form to re-evaluate what "centered" means?

Comment: Maybe read up on GetSystemMetrics.  I haven't used personally, but it can retrieve dimension of windows/screens you're on and then you can use MoveWindow to resize and move your form in relation to the window you are in.

Comment: what do you mean by ` the form is far 'off screen' in its own window ` ???

Comment: The menu will not be visible, and there will be a scrollbar at the bottom of the pane. I have to scroll the scrollbar all the way to the right to bring the form back into view, and then the scrollbar goes away with the form up against the right edge fo the pane.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are centering. The easiest way for objects to be dynamic is to use the form layout tool called "Anchoring". I like to make my layout expand to fill up the window to allow centered objects to remain centered as the window changes.

Comment: If I use anchoring to center, it stretches everything across. This is great for a title but will play havok with buttons and fields.

Comment: The buttons and fields can be controlled in a layout that has blank members on all side that you want dynamic padding. You can tell the blank cells of the layout to expand on either side. Each cell of a layout can have it's own anchoring rules.